# Redirect/rewrite home page domain.com to store view domain.com/en/

Tags: url-rewrite, redirect, home, htaccess

I have enabled `Add Store Code to Urls` to access the different store views of my Magento website, but now `www.domain.com` and `www.domain.com/en/` have the same content. To avoid duplicate content I would like to redirect `www.domain.com` (just the home page) to `www.domain.com/en/`.

How can I achieve this by using `.htaccess` or any other intelligent method? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for this as well. I just can't understand why Magento does not do this by default. I could not get this to work by using `.htaccess`

But here's what looks like an intelligent method by [Daniel Sloof](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51133/daniel-sloof) that seems to work perfectly fine for my store, so kudo's to him for developing this little module!

> **Note:** The original `<code>` for the module can be found on
>   [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480378/magento-store-code-to-urls-at-homepage),
>   but I'll post it below for easier future reference.

1. app/code/local/Danslo/RedirectToStore/Model/Observer.php

   ```
   <?php

   class Danslo_RedirectToStore_Model_Observer
   {

       public function redirectToStore($observer)
       {
           $request    = $observer->getFront()->getRequest();
           $storeCode  = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
           $requestUri = $request->getRequestUri();

           if (strpos($requestUri, $storeCode) === false) {
               $targetUrl = $request->getBaseUrl() . '/' . $storeCode;
               header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
               header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
               header('Pragma: no-cache');
               header('Location: ' . $targetUrl);
               exit;
           }
       }

   }
   ```
2. app/code/local/Danslo/RedirectToStore/etc/config.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <config>
       <global>
           <events>
               <controller_front_init_before>
                   <observers>
                       <redirect_to_store>
                           <class>Danslo_RedirectToStore_Model_Observer</class>
                           <method>redirectToStore</method>
                           <type>singleton</type>
                       </redirect_to_store>
                   </observers>
               </controller_front_init_before>
           </events>
       </global>
   </config>
   ```
3. app/etc/modules/Danslo_RedirectToStore.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <config>
       <modules>
           <Danslo_RedirectToStore>
               <active>true</active>
               <codePool>local</codePool>
           </Danslo_RedirectToStore>
       </modules>
   </config>
   ```

> **Note 2:** To add a trailing slash to the URL (like Magento does when clicking your stores logo) I made a small modification to Daniels
>   `Observer.php` file and changed
>
> ```
> $targetUrl = $request->getBaseUrl() . '/' . $storeCode;
> ```
>
> into
>
> ```
> $targetUrl = $request->getBaseUrl() . '/' . $storeCode . '/';
> ```

In addition to this, I also added to store code of my default store view to `index.php`

so

```
/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';
```

now looks like

```
/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : 'en';
```

This does not seem to be entirely necessary, but I ran into this when Googling for a solution...

Hope this helps someone. If there is a better option or room for improvement, then please comment!

Answer (score 0):

i discovered there is more than one base_url definition in the core_config_data table

if you run

```
select * from core_config_data where path like '%base_url%'
```

You should see all of the definitions
the scope was different on this definition and was overriding the default which i had already changed.