# Magento 1.9 : Redirect url with store code

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect

I have multi language website.

In my website, I want to redirect using controller to actual path of the website.

For ex. Currently, I redirect to

> www.example.com/testing/

But, I need to redirect like

> www.example.com/de/testing/

How to do it?

Anyone please help me.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37970/redirect-rewrite-home-page-domain-com-to-store-view-domain-com-en](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37970/redirect-rewrite-home-page-domain-com-to-store-view-domain-com-en)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this code. It maybe helpful to you :

```
$redirectpath = Mage::getUrl(' ', array('_direct' => 'testing'));

$this->_redirectUrl($redirectpath);
```

Comment: You should really add some context to this answer.  For instance, where does this code go?  What do you expect it to do?  Why should it do that?  I expect for from someone with 2K, and you clearly need to brush up on [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass store_id in the second parameter to have correct store

Try to use this

```
echo Mage::getUrl(' ',array('_store'=>1));
```

where "2" is your store_id

You can find more information

https://magento2.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/m1wiki/pages/14024861/getUrl+Function+Parameters

Answer (score 0):

First you Override File

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/switch/stores.phtml

After You can need to redirect like.....

Language1
   [Language2](http://www.example.com/de/testing/)